# install libicu-dev libicu-dev:i386 at the same time produce error at Ubuntu18 (on Ubuntu16 works fine)

Tags: apt

apt-get install libicu-dev libicu-dev:i386 produces error on ubuntu18, but works fine at ubuntu16. Does anybody have any ideas? See P.S. for details and PP.S. for OS information

Artem.

P.S.

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev libicu-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libicu-dev:i386 is already the newest version (60.2-3ubuntu3).
libicu-dev:i386 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libicu-dev : Conflicts: libicu-dev:i386 but 60.2-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libicu-dev:i386 : Conflicts: libicu-dev but 60.2-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

PP.S.

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behaviour.

If you compare the filelists of both packages obtained from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libicu-dev you will see that they have at least one identical filepath */usr/bin/icu-config*:

- [amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libicu-dev/filelist):

  > [image: amd64]
- [i386](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/libicu-dev/filelist)

  > [image: i386]

So you should not have these two packages installed in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer, I got it. This approach doesn't allow to build both i386 & amd64 c++ application at the single machine at single time. For example centos7 & redhat7 allow to install i686 & x86_64 packages at the same time. As far as I understand this approach as designed and no way to install these packages at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug that was fixed in Debian (on 2019-01-24) but it is not fixed in Ubuntu yet (2019-07-12):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icu/+bug/1784135

Because of it, it is also not possible to use i386 ICU dependent libraries such as libxml2.

I found this issue when I was trying to fix such compilation issue:

```
echo "int main(){return 0;}" > /tmp/a.cc && g++ /tmp/a.cc -lxml2 -o x64.bin && g++ /tmp/a.cc -m32 -lxml2 -o i386.bin
```

to compile it on x64 I need libxml2-dev:i386 which contains /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so but I cannot install it because of:

```
libxml2-dev:i386 : Depends: libicu-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

(libicu-dev:i386 conflicts with libicu-dev)